# TraceProcessing Library Support for VAMAP Data?

Tags: c#, .net-traceprocessing

I am missing Map/Unmap information in TraceProcessing. Are these exposed? TraceEvent has these exposed:

```
public event Action<MapFileTraceData> FileIOMapFile
        source.RegisterEventTemplate(new MapFileTraceData(value, 65535, 6, "FileIO", FileIOTaskGuid, 37, "MapFile", ProviderGuid, ProviderName, State));

public event Action<MapFileTraceData> FileIOUnmapFile
        source.RegisterEventTemplate(new MapFileTraceData(value, 65535, 6, "FileIO", FileIOTaskGuid, 38, "UnmapFile", ProviderGuid, ProviderName, State));

public event Action<MapFileTraceData> FileIOMapFileDCStart
        source.RegisterEventTemplate(new MapFileTraceData(value, 65535, 6, "FileIO", FileIOTaskGuid, 39, "MapFileDCStart", ProviderGuid, ProviderName, State));

public event Action<MapFileTraceData> FileIOMapFileDCStop
        source.RegisterEventTemplate(new MapFileTraceData(value, 65535, 6, "FileIO", FileIOTaskGuid, 40, "MapFileDCStop", ProviderGuid, ProviderName, State));
```

The MapFileTraceData defines

```
public sealed class MapFileTraceData : TraceEvent
{
  public ulong ViewBase
  public ulong FileKey
  public long MiscInfo
  public ulong ViewSize
  public string FileName
}
```